# Gaussian vs non-gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions, estimation

Let we have data of 3D (example angular velocity x, angular velocity y, angular velocity z).Can anyone explain/give example/how to differentiate between gaussian distribution and non-gaussian distribution of data since the difference is important for us to make decision whether to use Kalman filter or particle filter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a range of tests you could use. One of them, Mardia's test, is implemented in R by the function `mardia()` from the `dprep` package. Another possible test is Henze-Zirkler’s Multivariate Normality Test, which can be found in the `MVN` package.

For an overview of multivariate normality tests, see ["Invariant tests for multivariate normality: 
a critical review "](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00362-002-0119-6).